# Letting a user SSH into a contained environment

Tags: ssh

Let's say I have a user on my system (Ubuntu 16.04).

Is there a way to make sure that it can only SSH into some kind of virtual environment, but make it think it has sudo rights?

Can Linux namespaces help? How do I apply chroot or namespacing in a user connecting from ssh?

Edit: Assuming telnet is disabled, are there any other ways besides SSH to access my machine remotely?

Comment: The computer (generally servers) can be accessed using remote console, if it supports it and it is configured.

Answer (score 3):

`chroot` is useless for security (fine for other reasons like running programs that need it) if the user is root, because changing the current chroot requires root privileges.  So a `chroot`'ed root user simply has to do a `chroot /` to escape.

In Linux, LXC takes advantage of namespacing to effectively create a lightweight virtual machine.  I experimented with this a couple years ago and believe it was possible for root to break out of an LXC by accessing the `/proc` filesystem, which provides an interface to creating and managing existing containers.  This may be better now.

For security, the best thing I know of to do currently is create a VM using some type of VM software, whether VMWare, QEMU, or other.  QEMU in particular supports dropping rights once the VM is started, so the whole VM will not have root privileges on the system - this doesn't affect anything happening *in* the VM of course.

You will have to recreate the environment you want in the VM, and since the VM is pretty much a separate physical system, you will have to separately update it, provide it enough disk space for a full OS, etc.  But there is no way for programs running in the VM to escape it, barring any vulnerabilities in the VM software.